# libtool library version numbering

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, gnu, libtool

currently I'm linking a successfully built library with the option

```
libtool --mode=link g++ -version-info 1:0
```

which results in a library named

```
libxxx.so.1.0.0
```

This is fine so far. My question: how can I influence the last digit in the version scheme, mean how can I have a different value than 0 at the end of the library name?

Thanks!

Comment: Option `-version-info` has a sophisticated way to encode major and minor version numbers. That means it is hard to learn and easy to forget. Luckily there is a `-version-number` option too, that takes argument in `major:minor:patchlevel` form.

Answer (score 3):

Please refer to "Updating library version information" in the [Libtool manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/html_node/Updating-version-info.html), it explains the meaning of these numbers and why `-version-info 1:0:3` is invalid:

> If you want to use libtool’s versioning system, then you must specify the version information to libtool using the `-version-info` flag during link mode (see Link mode).
>
> This flag accepts an argument of the form *current[:revision[:age]]*. So, passing `-version-info 3:12:1` sets current to 3, revision to 12, and age to 1.
>
> If either revision or age are omitted, they default to 0. Also note that *age must be less than or equal to the current interface number.*
>
> Here are a set of rules to help you update your library version information:
>
> 1. Start with version information of *0:0:0* for each libtool library.
> 2. Update the version information only immediately before a public release of your software. More frequent updates are unnecessary, and only guarantee that the current interface number gets larger faster.
> 3. If the library source code has changed at all since the last update, then increment revision (*c:r:a* becomes *c:r+1:a*).
> 4. If any interfaces have been added, removed, or changed since the last update, increment current, and set revision to 0.
> 5. If any interfaces have been added since the last public release, then increment age.
> 6. If any interfaces have been removed or changed since the last public release, then set age to 0.
>
> **Never** try to set the interface numbers so that they correspond to the release number of your package. This is an abuse that only fosters misunderstanding of the purpose of library versions. Instead, use the `-release` flag (see Release numbers), but be warned that every release of your package will not be binary compatible with any other release.

You may also want to read about Library Versioning in the [Autotools Mythbuster](https://autotools.io/libtool/version.html) for a more extensive treatment of the matter.

Answer (score 1):

> how can I influence the last digit in the version scheme

You can influence it by specifying it:

```
-version-info 1:0:3
```

Comment: Unfortunately not, when I set "-version-info 1:0:1" this results in a library "libxxx.so.0.1.0"